# Issue: cannot connect to the Docker daemon

Tags: docker-daemon

I have created a Ubuntu base image and installing Docker in that base image. The installation was successful but I'm not sure why this docker daemon is not running.

Here is my docker file

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y

\#SHARED TOOLS
RUN apt update && apt install -y curl
RUN apt update && apt install -y unzip

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -

RUN apt update && apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg-agent software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
RUN add-apt-repository "deb \[arch=amd64\] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
RUN apt update && apt install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

Error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
root@b114bf803d3a:/# service docker status

* Docker is not running
```

I have restarted the services as well, but still my docker daemon is not running.

Comment: Are you running Windows? This error usually shows up on Windows devices if you try and run a Docker container in the command line without having Docker Desktop open.

Comment: im using windows machine and docker desktop is running fine